# Enthalpy of vaporization temperature dependence equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

Does an equation for the enthalpy of vaporization, $\Delta H_{vap}$ as a function of temperature, $T$, over a large temperature range exist? I have seen some sources mention Watson's Law as a possible equation but that this is flawed for a larger temperature range (say ranging from the melting point to the critical point of a material).

If such an equation exists, can it be easily applied to elements in their liquid phase (eg liquid Ag), or are there underlying issues?

Comment: Enthalpy of vaporization applies to a constant temperature phase change.  So I'm not sure what you mean by $\Delta H_{vap}$ being a function of temperature. Can you cite a reference?

Comment: @BobD, the heat of vaporization varies with the boiling temperature, and vanishes at the critical point.  I'm sure this is what the OP is referring to.

Comment: @DavidWhite Of course it does, just look at the steam tables for water.  But it wasn't clear (at least to me) that that was what was meant.

Comment: @tjsmert44, try this: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=equation+for+heat+of+vaporization&atb=v249-1&iax=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pirika.com%2Fimages%2FHv1.jpg&ia=images

Comment: The temperature variation of heat of vaporization can be determined using Hess’ Law.  You need to know the heat capacity variations of the saturated vapor and liquid.

Answer (score 0):

At an equilibrium phase change, the Gibbs free energies $G\equiv H-TS$ of the two phases are equal, with enthalpy $H$, temperature $T$, and entropy $S$. Thus, upon vaporization,

$$\Delta G=\Delta H-T_\mathrm{vap}\Delta S=0;$$

$$\Delta H=T_\mathrm{vap}(S_\mathrm{gas}-S_\mathrm{liquid}),$$

where $T_\mathrm{vap}$ is the vaporization temperature at that pressure. From $C_P\equiv T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P$, where $C$ is the constant-pressure heat capacity, we have $S=S_{T_\mathrm{vap}}+\int \frac{C_P}{T}dT$. Putting this together, we have

\begin{align}\Delta H&=T_\mathrm{vap}\left(S_{\mathrm{gas},T_\mathrm{vap}}+\int \frac{C_{P,\mathrm{gas}}}{T}dT-S_{\mathrm{liquid},T_\mathrm{vap}}-\int \frac{C_{P,\mathrm{liquid}}}{T}dT\right);\\&=\Delta H_{T_\mathrm{vap}}+T_\mathrm{vap}\left(\int \frac{C_{P,\mathrm{gas}}}{T}dT-\int \frac{C_{P,\mathrm{liquid}}}{T}dT\right).\end{align}

This equation applies over large temperature ranges with varying $C_P$. If $C_P$ can be assumed constant, we have the simpler

$$\Delta H=\Delta H_{T_\mathrm{vap}}+T_\mathrm{vap}\left[\left(C_{P,\mathrm{gas}}-C_{P,\mathrm{liquid}}\right)\ln\left(\frac{T}{T_\mathrm{vap}}\right)\right].$$

In turn, for small temperature changes $\Delta T$, a Taylor series expansion of the logarithm function gives

$$\Delta H\approx\Delta H_{T_\mathrm{vap}}+\left(C_{P,\mathrm{gas}}-C_{P,\mathrm{liquid}}\right)\Delta T.$$

To this we can apply further approximations; for example, the molar heat capacity of solids is often around $3R$, and every physics student is familiar with estimates of molar heat capacity of ideal gases (e.g., $\frac{7}{2}R$ for the constant-pressure molar heat capacity of a diatomic ideal gas). See also, for example, Zhang's "[Thermophysical interpretation of the latent heat of vaporization of water](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00514486)."

Comment: How are you defining $T_{vap}$ here? Wouldn't this depend on the ambient vapor pressure since the boiling point is defined with an ambient atmosphere of 1bar? How would this change for a vacuum system?

Comment: I don't see why these equations wouldn't apply for any pressure. I edited my answer to explicitly note that $T_\mathrm{vap}$ is the vaporization temperature at the pressure being considered.